# When a user add a new row to a specific sheet, it adds automatically the same to another Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

My first Google sheet (sheet1) looks like this:

```
Date    Name    Origin Exchange Destination Exchange    Amount (WITH FEES)  Currency    Reason
25/02/19 14:51  Kraken Jeremy   Kraken Corporate    0.4000  BTC we will start using corporate 
25/02/19 14:53  Kraken Jeremy   Zebpay Corporate    0.75917 BTC we will start using corporate
```

What I would like to achieve is when an employee adds a row to that sheet, it automatically fills in another sheet. Do I have to code or is there an option to do that easily?

Comment: Is the additional row always on a single sheet like Sheet2 or dependent on some value on sheet1?

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald, I did not really understood your question... the row that is written is Sheet1 should be exactly copied in Sheet2.

Comment: In Excel on Sheet2 in cell A1 you could enter `=Sheet1!A1`, fill A1 across row 1 to column G then fill down far enough to cover the maximum number of rows likely to be on sheet1.  I suspect this brute force approach isn't what you are looking for though.  If you want Sheet2 to be dynamic you'll have to use VBA in Excel or whatever Google Sheets use for a programming language.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

put this formula to **A1** in **sheet2**:

```
=QUERY(sheet1!A1:Z; "select * where A is not null"; 1)
```